# Why was Matlab written in C instead of Fortran?

Tags: c, matlab, programming-languages, fortran

As you may know, Fortran is a language for scientific computing. however, the kernel of the most famous high level language for scientific computing has been written in C instead of Fortran. Why?

Comment: This doesn't make sense - the title and question differ. Do you mean why was matlab written in C or why was Fortran written in C?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear he means the former. Fortran is a low-level language and in fact pre-dates C, so the latter wouldn't make any sense anyway.

Comment: I think the kernel of matlab should have been written in Fortran not C assuming Fortran is better for scientific computing.

Comment: Not to be pedantic but isn't FORTRAN the most famous language in scientific computing? Or am I just stuck in the 1970s and 1980s?

I am sure that all modern Fortran compilers are written in C or C++ and have been for many years.

Comment: I won't even try to resolve the gordian knot these comments made. I think he means why was MATLAB written in C, and not written in fortran. Because, simply, fortran is not the best tool for such a job. C is better. Nowadays, fortran compilers are also written in C and a little lower level languages for high optimization. What a compiler for some language is written in, has nothing to do with that language - it is the problem-solving-time in that language and run-time required to run the problem while using program written in that language that matters.

Comment: For scientific problem fortran is an excellent exanmple of low level language. Matlab is a little higher oriented, but tends to be slower (disclaimer: read the last part with caution).

Comment: I don't have the rep yet to tag this as subjective, so would someone else mind doing it?

Comment: I STRONGLY disagree with the "subjective" tag. Matlab's choice of C over Fortran is NOT a subjective/personal choice in this specific subject! If others agree I would suggest editing the tags to remove subjective.

Comment: Here, I removed it - if somebody wants it, let him put it himself. I can see Trevor's point of view though; C or better to say C++ is objectively a better language for writing a full blown application (I wouldn't like to try writing it in pure C either, its just sometimes I regard those as one and the same in discussions).

Comment: "For scientific problem fortran is an excellent exanmple of low level language." No. Fortran is no "low level language". Assembler is low level. Matlab is a software suite including addons, tool boxes, solvers, plotting features, or if you wish just basic coding. For the question: C, because maybe out of 1,000 employees, 80 % know C instead of Fortran. Or, because of the hundreds of changes of computer hardware from the 1960s onwards, combined with the success of C moving along those changes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**To answer your original question: Matlab was originally written in Fortran.**  But one of the first things that the creator of Matlab, Cleve Moler, and his partner did in 1983 was to rewrite the entire Matlab app in C:

> Jack Little left his job at the
>   consulting company and bought a new
>   COMPAQ portable computer at Sears. The
>   machine had only 256 KB of memory and
>   no hard disc; Jack had to swap
>   5-1/4-inch floppies to compile
>   programs. Jack and Steve took a year
>   and a half to re- write MATLAB in C,
>   adding new features they had envi-
>   sioned. ([The Growth of MATLAB and The MathWorks over Two Decades](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/news_notes/clevescorner/jan06.pdf))

**I think a more relevant question for today would be to ask: why did they switch to C back in 1983 ?**

My guess is that C probably had certain features that Fortran did not have and thus the switch was more out of necessity and in the interest of code maintainability.

One *killer* feature missing in Fortran77 was dynamic memory allocation (Dynamic memory allocation was only added in Fortran90). Getting around that *single* limitation would be a horrible deal breaker in my opinion.

EDIT:

dmckee's answer has a great explanation of why using Fortran77 would be painful.

Comment: @Trevor Boyd Smith, Cleve Moler or Steve Moler? The first paragraph of your answer reads that Cleve Moler and his partner rewote MatLab, but in the quote it says Jack and Steve.

Answer (score 18):

Guessing on the basis of experience:

> Memory management.

Fortran (well, the fortran that was around when matlab was written) has no support for dynamic memory management. Which makes it a pain for big work (see, for instance, [CERNLIB](http://cernlib.web.cern.ch/cernlib/)).

CERNLIB solves the problem by allocating a whopping big array in a common block, and implementing a malloc like (de)allocator for the cells of the array. Clunky but working: array offsets are pointer equivalents, and away you go...

Comment: So CERNLIB basically hacked in the same functionality of malloc()/free() into Fortran77? 

Why didn't they just use C?

Comment: Parts of CERNLIB date to the early 1960s. By the time c came around they already had a lot of code. I believe large parts were rewritten several times, but the deal breaker was: physicists. Even into the '80s most physicists only spoke fortran.

Comment: *shakes head*. I hate dinosaurs ("dinosaur" is my euphemism for people who suceeded in some manner and are now stuck in their way and refuse to change). I guess a meteor came and wiped out all the Fortran Physicists in the 80s?  What specifically was the "meteor" that forced the Physicists to change in the 80s?

Comment: "What specifically was the "meteor" that forced the Physicists to change in the 80s?" Incoming students who knew Pascal and c? Or the rise of unix? But the change was/is incremental and is still going on. CERNLIB has been largely superceded by ROOT, but there are millions of LOC out there, and it is still actively supported. Heck I wrote code against it just 18 months ago.

Comment: @Trevor Boyd Smith - I wouldn't say there was a meteor at all. Nowadays, most engineers and physicists are familiar with fortran - at my college (nav. arch) we were taught fortran, some were taught py and matlab, but none learned C. C is the language of cs students - most engineers don't use it, unless they're programming inclined (but that's their own personal business). And let's be frank, when it comes to scientific purposes fortran is still much better suited than C, python, or most others (matlab is nice, but has some drawbacks when performance comes into the run) - just

Comment: think "multidimensional arrays" (yes, try doing tensor calculus in C and in fortran).

Comment: Pascal is another story - it is a nice language (I've noticed it is, and has always been, popular among mathematicians) - but nowadays its future is somewhat uncertain. Apart from Borland's Delphi (and Borland's future is also somewhat uncertain) it lacks support and its userbase is somewhat fading (these are just my observations).

Comment: > I hate dinosaurs. 
You have a library with KLocs of Fortran written by experts over 40years - you are just going to convert it to C. Do you understand all those equations? All the rounding errors? All the edge cases? 

And you are going to do this in a language that doesn't have matrices or complex numbers as standard yet.

Comment: @ldigas: In my end of the business (particle physics), many student *don't* know or learn fortran anymore. C++ predominates, presumably because it's the language of ROOT. They also don't *write* the tensor manipulation code, they just bring in a robust library.

Comment: @mgb - I really can't understand from your tone whether you're being sarcastic or not. Fortran does have matrices and complex as a standard.

Comment: @dmckee - That probably varies from country to country. I know several chaps in your area of work here (Croatia); they still use it extensively. With the new standard, it is very easy to do that kind of calculations directly (indexing in fortran 95 and onwards is very nicely handled). In my area of work, unfortunatelly, since not many people do it, there is no such thing as robust libraries (or libraries of any kind) but there is a great need for intensive computations in several fields.

Comment: But, just not to get this going in another flame war - I'd say that we can all agree - "use what you wish, and what you think is a good tool for the job" - those three, c, fortran and matlab - are very nicely interconnectible today, so ...

Answer (score 12):

My understanding is that Matlab is written in a hodge-podge of languages, including but not limited to C, FORTRAN, Java, and Matlab itself.

I believe it employs best-of-breed libraries behind the scenes, including LAPACK (FORTRAN), FFTW (C) and probably many more.

I think the original version was pure FORTRAN, but as it became more polished and commercial they weren't shy about using the right language for each component.  I don't blame them--I'd hate to write a parser or a GUI in FORTRAN!

Comment: I wouldn't like to write a parser even in C. But yes, you're correct - early versions were written in fortran, then they switched to C (completely rewrote the thing) at some point.

Comment: +1 for accuracy. Matlab runs on top of a Java JRE. Presumably much of it is either in .m files or in Java, w/ the exception of time-critical stuff that is proven to be faster when implemented in native code. I remember when they switched to a Java version; it slowed things down, but now that the JRE has been made faster it's not bad & definitely worth being able to use Java objects within MATLAB.

Comment: Someday I will learn how to use Java objects within Matlab... someday.

Answer (score 10):

I want to qualify this answer with the following statement - I know nothing about Fortran or Matlab

However i think you almost answer your own question in your question.

Why would you not use a scientific language to write a kernel. You would use the most appropriate language for the task at hand. A kernel would be best written in C as it is better suited to working with low level tasks like kernels (working with memory management etc)

A Kernel is not a scientific application therefore you wouldn't use a scientific language.

Again, i may be completely off the mark but i think that is a highly logical answer.

Comment: A quick note: the kernel of a computational software package is not the same thing as the kernel of an operating system. In the first case, the kernel is the underlying computational engine, which the user interacts with through a higher-level user interface (e.g. the MATLAB command window or the Mathematica notebook interface).

Answer (score 3):

You can find some information on the origins of Matlab by viewing a video on their web site, specifically on the [page](http://www.mathworks.com/company/aboutus/founders/clevemoler.html) of the Chief Scientist, Cleve Moler.

Answer (score 3):

Matlab was originally written in Fortran, it was more a less a wrapper for a bunch 
of Fortran routines. So the question is why rewrite it in c? In fact why did Fortran lose
out to c and other languages that weren't really suited to numerical computing. The answer is Fortran suffered badly from politics. For various reasons the standard committee could decide  on a replacement for Fortran 77. So,  by the time Fortran 90 eventually came out Fortran had lost a lot of ground to other languages. This situation has now been corrected. Fortran 2003, which is  more or less implemented in the gnu compiler, is a nice language its well suited to numeric and in addition has dynamic allocation fast io and OO ish constructs polymorphism derived type etc. (Fortran 2008 will be even better)

Modern Fortran isn't designed to write gui interfaces but it is designed to call and be called from C and other languages. So if the matlab exercise was repeated today its quite possible that the numeric bits would be written in Fortran and the user interface in something else.

Comment: is this a typo? "arious reasons the standard committee could decide" -> "could not decide" ?